# How Can i detect Touch Screen In c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, touch, blazor-webassembly, touch-event

I want to create a web application using Blazor that consists of two lists, each containing different buttons. I would like to hide the buttons when it is touch screen and make it possible for users to select individual items in the lists using touch input.
I'm new to Blazor and programming, and I would greatly appreciate assistance from someone who can help me.

this is the code for the two lists

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-4 content-component-wrapper h-[500px]">
        <!-- Left Side -->
        <div class="bg-[#ddd] overflow-scroll">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Response.name.Count / 2; i++)
            {
                <div style="color:@Response.name[i].ForeColorHexCode; background-color:@Response.name[i].BackColorHexCode; @(selectedLeftRowIndex == i ? "border: 4px solid blue !important;" : "")"
                     class="p-4 m-2" id="left-row-@i">
                    <h4 class="text-lg font-semibold">@Response.name[i].GlobalName</h4>
                    <p>@Response.name[i].ID</p>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <!-- Right Side -->
        <div class="bg-[#ddd] overflow-scroll">
            @for (int i = Response.name.Count / 2; i < Response.name.Count; i++)
            {
                <div style="color:@Response.name[i].ForeColorHexCode; background-color:@Response.name[i].BackColorHexCode; @(selectedRightRowIndex == i ? "border: 4px solid blue !important;" : "")"
                     class="p-4 m-2" id="right-row-@i">
                    <h4 class="text-lg font-semibold">@Response.name[i].GlobalName</h4>
                    <p>@Response.name[i].ID</p>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<div class="flex justify-center space-x-4 md:space-x-6 lg:space-x-14 p-4 border-2 border-lightgray rounded-xl mb-8 mt-10">
        <button class="flex items-center justify-center w-36 h-36 text-lg md:w-44 md:h-44 lg:w-48 lg:h-42 font-semibold bg-gold text-white rounded-xl p-4 transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 focus:outline-none" @onclick="SelectLeftSideNextRow">
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
                <RadzenIcon Icon="arrow_downward" class="mb-2 text-xl md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl" />
                <span class="text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg">@translationStore.Translations["Down"]</span>
            </div>
        </button>
        <button class="flex items-center justify-center w-36 h-36 text-lg md:w-44 md:h-44 lg:w-48 lg:h-42 font-semibold bg-gold text-white rounded-xl p-4 transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 focus:outline-none" @onclick="SelectLeftSidePreviousRow" >
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
                <RadzenIcon Icon="arrow_upward" class="mb-2 text-xl md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl" />
                <span class="text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg">@translationStore.Translations["Up"]</span>
            </div>
        </button>
        <button class="flex items-center justify-center w-36 h-36 text-lg md:w-44 md:h-44 lg:w-48  lg:h-42 font-semibold bg-gold text-white rounded-xl p-4 transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 focus:outline-none">
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
                <RadzenIcon Icon="lists" class="mb-2 text-xl md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl" />
                <span class="text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg">@translationStore.Translations["Show"]</span>
            </div>
        </button>
        <button class="flex items-center justify-center w-36 h-36 text-lg md:w-44 md:h-44 lg:w-48  lg:h-42 font-semibold bg-gold text-white rounded-xl p-4 transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 focus:outline-none">
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
                <RadzenIcon Icon="hourglass_empty" class="mb-2 text-xl md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl" />
                <span class="text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg">@translationStore.Translations["History"]</span>
            </div>
        </button>
        <button class="flex items-center justify-center w-36 h-36 text-lg md:w-44 md:h-44 lg:w-48  lg:h-42 font-semibold bg-gold text-white rounded-xl p-4 transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 focus:outline-none" @onclick="SelectRightSideNextRow">
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
                <RadzenIcon Icon="arrow_downward" class="mb-2 text-xl md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl" />
                <span class="text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg" >@translationStore.Translations["Down"]</span>
            </div>
        </button>
        <button class="flex items-center justify-center w-36 h-36 text-lg md:w-44 md:h-44 lg:w-48  lg:h-42 font-semibold bg-gold text-white rounded-xl p-4 transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 focus:outline-none" @onclick="SelectRightSidePreviousRow">
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
                <RadzenIcon Icon="arrow_upward" class="mb-2 text-xl md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl" />
                <span class="text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg" >@translationStore.Translations["Up"]</span>
            </div>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://github.com/arivera12/BlazorCurrentDevice perhaps?

Comment: @Hades answer makes me remember, that some laptops come with a touch screen but the user isn't likely to want a touch-optimized UI. I think the flexbox size is a better cue of what appropriate UI the user might want.